# Android NetworkInterface.getInetAddresses method not working

Tags: android, sockets

I have an Android 4.0.4 rooted device connected to a LAN through an eth0 interface.
My application needs to have two IPs on the LAN so I added them with:

ip addr add  /24 brd + dev eth0
ip addr add  /24 brd + dev eth0

The command 'ip addr show' shows the addresses and I can ping both of them from other devices on the LAN.

My application needs to open sockets on both addresses so I use the NetworkInterface class to obtain them (there are several examples around), but the list relative to eth0 has just one entry. This prevents my application to open sockets on the second address.

Another curious thing is that both 'netcfg' and 'ifconfig' output indicate just one address (only 'ip addr show' is correct).

EDIT:

I have now read about this issue:

[code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36901](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36901)

Does anyone has a workaround for this? Is it possible to decompile/recompile the NetworkInterface class in android.jar? Or maybe calling another implementation through reflection or something?

Thank you for your help (sorry for my errors, it's the first time I post on StackOverflow...)

Elvio

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the [`INTERNET`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET) permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

You might also need [`ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: You should answer your own question with that, I'll delete this since it's not at all accurate.